# How to use the results of a query as the WHERE columns in another?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a bunch of columns with yes/no values. These are identified by their length being 3:

```
SELECT colname
  FROM syscat.columns 
  WHERE tabname='CL'
  AND length = 3
```

**I'd like to count all the rows that have a yes for any of these columns.**

So normally I'd do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM CL
  WHERE c1=yes or c2=yes or c3=yes #...
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to apply those column names in the WHERE clause of another query. Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(sub.*)
  FROM (
    SELECT colname
      FROM syscat.columns 
      WHERE tabname='CL'
      AND length = 3
  ) sub
  WHERE [sub] = yes #How can I say "The VALUE of each column name from the subquery"
```

What I'm looking for is a count of rows where any 3-length column has a 'yes'.

Note: I'm using db2 on bluemix, but any general information about this would be helpful.

Comment: Your "normally" query is the way to go. You can do a [**dynamic query**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785302/how-to-execute-an-sql-string-in-db2) using the information from "syscat.columns" is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 3):

For this you have to use dynamic sql, but you can make it simpler using the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CL
WHERE yes in(c1, c2, c3, c4, ....)
```

Using dynamic sql you can generate the list of columns' names comma separated from the following query:

```
SELECT colname
FROM syscat.columns 
WHERE tabname='CL'
  AND length = 3
```

Comment: So the sub-query really isn't necessary here - I'd still have to list out all the columns?

Comment: @TravisHeeter You cannot use the subquery directly in your query, you will use to compose the dynamic sql so that you can generate the list `c1, c2, c3, c4 , ...` then execute the dynamic sql query.

Comment: unfortunately  I am not familiar with db2, but this is how you can do it.

Comment: Actually this is far from the final query. You arent querying the table with rows.