# Function with different returns DB2

Tags: sql, function, if-statement, db2, return

Hi I have this function:

```
 CREATE or replace FUNCTION Tablereturn (SWITCHER INTEGER)
 RETURNS TABLE (Test CHAR(9),
                tester INTEGER
                )
 LANGUAGE SQL
 CONTAINS SQL
 DETERMINISTIC
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION
 BEGIN 

   DECLARE SELECT1, SELECT2 VARCHAR(1024);
   set select1 ='SELECT TEST, TESTER FROM TESTTAB';
   set select2 ='SELECT DUMMY, JAR, BRAND FROM TESTTAB';
 IF (SWITCHER = '1') THEN return select1;
 ELSEIF (SWITCHER = '2') THEN return select2;
  END IF; 
   RETURN TABLE;
   END@
```

Calling would be

```
select TEST from TABLE(Tablereturn(1))@
```

or

```
select JAR from TABLE(Tablereturn(2))@
```

The problem is, that it doesn't work. Compiler says that after return the unexpected Token "SELECT1" is there.
I want to be able to call it as a table and select values as I need them from the call. 
I can't just call it as a procedure with the select as return, since I need to work with the select as a table and change the returned output in a bigger select. Can I have EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in a function?

Any ideas? The other question is, how can I make the function return different tables? The select2 returns 3 values while select1 returns only 2.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785302/how-to-execute-an-sql-string-in-db2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute an SQL string in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785302/how-to-execute-an-sql-string-in-db2)

Comment: It doesn't compile because the select1 is not accepted

Comment: Don't see why it is a duplicate?

Comment: Can I have EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in a Function?

Comment: There's another problem in select2... "SELECT DUMMY, JAR, BRAND "... you select 3 fields and you need only 2 fields...

Comment: Try to declare SELECT1 and 2 in distinct row : `DECLARE SELECT1 VARCHAR (1024) DEFAULT '' ;  DECLARE SELECT2 VARCHAR (1024) DEFAULT '' ;`

Answer (score 3):

RETURN statement must be the last statement of the function. There is a class of functions called 'pipelined' where you can use 'if then else' logic. Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_PIPELINED(P_CHOICE INT)
RETURNS TABLE (R_COL1 VARCHAR(128), R_COL2 VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN 
  DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
  DECLARE L_COL1 VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_COL2 VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR S1;

  IF P_CHOICE=1 THEN
    PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT COLNAME, COLNO FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY';
  ELSE 
    PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT TABNAME, OWNER   FROM SYSCAT.TABLES  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY';
  END IF;

  OPEN c1;
  L1: LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO L_COL1, L_COL2;
    IF SQLSTATE<>'00000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
    PIPE(L_COL1, L_COL2);
  END LOOP L1;
  CLOSE c1;
  RETURN;
END@
```

Comment: Is there also a way to have different tables returned depending on P_CHOICE?

Comment: If you ask about result sets of different structure, then no, you can't. Your result set must have the same structure as declared in the 'RETURN TABLE (...)' clause. We do have a class of functions called 'generic', where you can declare the result set structure at run-time. But they can be JAVA (external) functions only, but not SQL ones.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `PIPE` would be something simple like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_CHOICE(P_CHOICE INT)
RETURNS TABLE (R_COL1 VARCHAR(128), R_COL2 VARCHAR(128))
RETURN
    SELECT COLNAME, TYPENAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE P_CHOICE = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TABNAME, OWNER     FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE P_CHOICE = 2
;
```