# How can I access a Table whose name is mentioned as a key value in another Table in SQL Db2

Tags: sql, db2, websphere

[Table1] contains a column "ID" that has Values. Each of these values correspond to a Table Name in the database.
How can I access those tables by calling them from the ID column in [TABLE1]

example:

```
ID:
3
4
6
8
```

each of those IDs correspond to a table
and I want to access those tables through the Values stored in ID column of [TABLE1]

Comment: Add some examples like a SELECT statement or details of how you want to use it. And what Db2 version and platform? It seems you are asking for composing a SELECT statement based on read input ("dynamic SQL"). There are answers here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: IBM DB2 on cloud, what I am using is : SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ID FROM TABLE1).. I am pretty sure that It's big time wrong... i am still new

Comment: You must have some `TABLE1.ID -> (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME)` mapping between your ID and full table name (which consists of table schema and table name). Nobody knows it except you. If you know such a mapping, you must construct and run the corresponding `SELECT * FROM TABSCHEMA.TABNAME` statement either manually or programmatically.

Comment: it it possible using a SQL script and  EXECUTE or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785302/how-to-execute-an-sql-string-in-db2